# opencv import error (libopencv_dnn.so.3.4 undefined symbol)

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

System information:

```
Ubuntu 16.04, Anaconda 1.6.9, Python 3.6.4, libopencv 3.4.1, opencv 3.4.1, py-opencv 3.4.1.
```

Problem definition: I just upgraded my `opencv` to `3.4` through anaconda and found could not import.

The import error is:

> ImportError: anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/../../libopencv_dnn.so.3.4: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message25InitializationErrorStringB5cxx11Ev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution works for me, although not sure why and how.

1. `conda install -c defaults libprotobuf protobuf`
2. `conda install -c menpo opencv3`

Comment: Seems to work here too https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9601

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this answer from [GitHub](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3046):

> 1. Configure /usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h as suggested. 
>      (**remove the gcc 5 error from the CUDA header host_config.h**)
> 2. `sudo apt-get autoremove libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler`
> 3. then compile the protobuf-2.5.0 from src and install Please config the gcc when you
>      compile protobuf ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ CC=/usr/bin/gcc

Also (GitHub user [groakat](https://github.com/groakat) mentions):

> for me this problem was caused because I had protobuf installed in
>   anaconda. If you have protobuf installed in your anaconda environment,
>   you have to remove all files by hand, as conda uninstall protobuf does
>   not remove all the library files.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. But it seems I don't have the path `/usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h`, but I have `cudatoolkit` installed on my Anaconda, that's strange.

Comment: I also don't understand why does the error involve caffe?